# JFreeChart losing data in dynamic chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have dynamic chart for measuring CPU performance and I need my Java program to generate chart for a long period of time (for example: 24h). Problem is that as new data comes older ones disappear form chart. I don't want to lose that data. 
Can I somehow make x-axis fixed? 
Is there posibility to implement auto scroll on chart or to compress graph?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6517440/230513), you can use `setMaximumItemAge()` in a `TimeSeries` to decide how much data to retain. You can also use `setMaximumItemCount()`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no sample code, so we don't know how and when you generate a chart. But in general: if you don't want to lose information in the chart, you need to save new data without discarding the old data (e.g. in a database, just in a class variable ArrayList etc., whatever you need). If you generate the chart, use that data, and expect a dynamic size/amount of values. (It has to be generated upon request, or with a timer)